# Enzyme testing an authentication Higher Order Component (HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, enzyme

I've created a Higher Order Component / Composed Component to ensure a user is authenticated before loading the Component. It's very basic, but I'm having some trouble testing it. I want to test the points below, which are similar to the tests I already have elsewhere:

- Renders the Component (I normally check by looking for a Component specific `className`)
- Has correct `props` (in my case `authenticated`)
- Renders the wrapped Component if `authenticated` and renders `null` if not

The HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

import { makeSelectAuthenticated } from 'containers/App/selectors';

export default function RequireAuth(ComposedComponent) {
  class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object,
    }

    static propTypes = {
      authenticated: React.PropTypes.bool,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) this.context.router.push('/');
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) this.context.router.push('/');
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="authenticated">
          { this.props.authenticated ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> : null }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    authenticated: makeSelectAuthenticated(),
  });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

I'm using `enzyme` and `jest` for my tests, but haven't found a way of rendering the HOC successfully during my tests.

Any ideas?

**Solution thanks to answer below:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { AuthenticatedComponent } from '../index';

describe('AuthenticatedComponent', () => {
  let MockComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    MockComponent = () => <div />;
    MockComponent.displayName = 'MockComponent';
  });

  it('renders its children when authenticated', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <AuthenticatedComponent
        composedComponent={MockComponent}
        authenticated={true}
      />,
      { context: { router: { push: jest.fn() } } }
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('MockComponent').length).toEqual(1);
  });

  it('renders null when not authenticated', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <AuthenticatedComponent
        composedComponent={MockComponent}
        authenticated={false}
      />,
      { context: { router: { push: jest.fn() } } }
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('MockComponent').length).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "tricky" part here is that your HOC returns a connected component, which makes testing harder because you have shallow render two layers (the connected component and the actual component) and you have to mock the redux store.

Instead you could define the `AuthenticatedComponent` upfront and export it as a named export. Than you can test it independently of `connect` like you test every other component:

```
export class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
  }

  static propTypes = {
    authenticated: React.PropTypes.bool,
    composedComponent: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.authenticated) this.context.router.push('/');
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.authenticated) this.context.router.push('/');
  }

  render() {
    const ComposedComponent = this.props.composedComponent;
    return (
      <div className="authenticated">
        { this.props.authenticated ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function RequireAuth(ComposedComponent) {
  const mapStateToProps = () => {
    const selectIsAuthenticated = makeSelectAuthenticated();
    return (state) => ({
      authenticated: selectIsAuthenticated(state),
      composedComponent: ComposedComponent,
    });
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

Example test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import RequireAuth, { AuthenticatedComponent } from '../';

const Component = () => <div />;
Component.displayName = 'CustomComponent';

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe.only('HOC', () => {
  const RequireAuthComponent = RequireAuth(Component);
  const context = { router: { push: jest.fn() } };
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={mockStore({})}>
      <RequireAuthComponent />
    </Provider>,
    {
      context,
      childContextTypes: { router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired },
    }
  );
  it('should return a component', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('Connect(AuthenticatedComponent)')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
  it('should pass correct props', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('AuthenticatedComponent').props()).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        authenticated: false,
        composedComponent: Component,
      })
    );
  });
});

describe('rendering', () => {
  describe('is authenticated', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <AuthenticatedComponent
        composedComponent={Component}
        authenticated
      />,
      { context: { router: { push: jest.fn() } } }
    );
    it('should render the passed component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('CustomComponent')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
  describe('is not authenticated', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <AuthenticatedComponent
        composedComponent={Component}
        authenticated={false}
      />,
      { context: { router: { push: jest.fn() } } }
    );
    it('should not render the passed component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('CustomComponent')).toHaveLength(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, is it possible for you to give an example of how to just render the component in the test? I've tried a lot of various methods using `shallow` and `mount` but can't seem to get anything to render correctly for testing.

Comment: Also, a bit confused by the `composedComponent` variable that you pass in to `mapStateToProps`. That will still act as normal?

Comment: Added an example of how you could test the `AuthenticatedComponent`. I agree using mapStateToProps to pass the `composedComponent` looks a bit weird. Since the `AuthenticatedComponent` is now defined outside of the HOC the only way we can pass it the `ComposedComponent` is via props. I figured we can just use `mapStateToProps` or this.

Comment: Awesome, I will post my final test file to the OP so you can check it, would be good to get your feedback. Marked this as the correct answer

Comment: I found one issue with your answer, when trying to load my wrapped component I use `export default RequireAuth(SomeComponent);` ...but I receive `The prop composedComponent is marked as required in AuthenticatedComponent, but its value is undefined`. Very strange because actually the tests are passing fine that I posted above.

Comment: Oh, Sorry did not see that you are using reselect! Will update the answer.

Comment: Still getting an error with the props, but will work on it. `HOC › encountered a declaration exception, TypeError: state.get is not a function` is the error which I assume is from the tests.

Comment: I tried it out before I posted it and I don't get any errors, neither in runtime in the app nor in the tests. Hope you can figure out what is going wrong :-)

Comment: Seems it comes from my global `state` selector: `const selectGlobal = (state) => state.get('global');`....No idea really :/

Comment: Since the example above is not using `createStructuredSelector` anymore you have to pass in the state manually like I do for `selectIsAuthenticated`. Are you doing that?

Comment: Don't think so, but I'm not sure where/what I would change as I'm also new to using `reselect`.

Comment: I believe it could be because of the fact im using `immutable` for the state, but have no clue on how to fix it -.- Could be the mockStore in the test suite

Comment: Seems to be passing the tests now, only issue is that when I log `this.props.authenticated` in the Component is that it is logged three times. The first time it is logged as a `function` whereas it is expected to be a `boolean`